# Check if a certain column contains a certain value when updating another column

Tags: sql, constraints, check-constraint

I'm having some trouble to find an easy way to check if a column contains a certain value before updating the value in another column in a table row. For example, if I have the table StudentsParticipationInClass like below

```
    |  ID  |  Grade  |  State  |
    |  1   |   'U'   |'OnGoing'|
    |  2   |   '3'   | 'Done'  |
```

I want a constraint that tells the user that to be able to update the state to Done the Grade must be something else than 'U' or NULL.

Comment: I suggest that you add some logic to your application code so that only records allowed to be updated be shown as such.

Comment: I want it to be at database level so that if another program is developed in the future it does'nt have to add that logic into it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:

`UPDATE StudentsParticipationInClass

SET State = 'Done'

WHERE Grade <> 'U'

AND WHERE Grade IS NOT NULL

AND WHERE ID = 1`

Comment: Is this SQL -> `Grade != 'U'`

Comment: I don't want it to be in an update query, I would like it as a check constraint so you dont have to worry about it in every update statement created later on

Comment: @Nadeem_MK , in some versions of SQL `!=` [it works](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), but yeah, `<>` seems better. Edited my answer.